# Json-Decoder-Error when trying to request api?

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping, request

i try to rebuild an request from this webpage:
https://www.hagglezon.com/

I try it with the following code:

```
import requests
if __name__ == '__main__':
  headers =   {
        'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36'
        }

  payload = {
  "operationName": "SearchResults",
  "variables": {
    "lang": "de",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "filters": {},
    "search": "Samsung",
    "page": 6,
    "country": "de"
  },
  "query": "query SearchResults($search: String!, $country: String, $currency: String!, $lang: String!, $page: Int, $filters: SearchFilters) {\n  searchProducts(searchTerm: $search, country: $country, productConfig: {language: $lang, currency: $currency}, page: $page, filters: $filters) {\n    products {\n      id\n      title\n      brand\n      tags\n      related_items\n      prices {\n        country\n        price\n        currency\n        url\n        __typename\n      }\n      all_images {\n        medium\n        large\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    next {\n      country\n      page\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"
}    
  url = "https://graphql.hagglezon.com/"
  resp = requests.post(url,data=payload, headers=headers).json()
```

Unfortunately i allways get the following error when trying to run the code:

```
$ python checkAPI.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Polzi\Documents\DEV\Fiverr\TRY\massimiliano393\checkAPI.py", line 3171, in <module>
    resp = requests.post(url,data=payload, headers=headers).json()
  File "C:\Users\Polzi\Documents\DEV\.venv\NormalScraping\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\polzi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "c:\users\polzi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "c:\users\polzi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode       
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Is there probably something wrong with the form i define the payload-variable?
How can i prevent this error-message and the request to run?

Comment: You need to *actually look at the response*, rather than immediately try to decode it as JSON, to see what's really there.  Perhaps it's an error message, instead of JSON.

Comment: Yes you are right - print(resp.status_code)  shows finally a 403-return code...